# Как изменить последовательность вывода блоков при изменении масштаба страницы?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Здравствуйте. Есть вот такая секция(скрин ниже). Как лучше исспользовать список или просто блокам float: left; прописать? Бог с ним с этим выравниванием. У меня другая проблема. Блоки изначально идут: 
картинка-1 текст-1 картинка-3 
текст-2 картинка-2 текст-3;

```css
ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 li{
   list-style-type: none;
   float: left;
 }
 
 .item{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="item">картинка - 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">текст - 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">картинка - 3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">текст - 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">картинка - 2</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">текст -3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать так чтобы при уменьшении размера экрана в 2-е колонки было так:

- картинка-1 текст-1
- картинка-2 текст-2
- картинка-3 текст-3

И в одну

- картинка-1
- текст-1
- картинка-2
- текст-2
- картинка-3
- текст-3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут можно вообще table использовать вместо этих ul li. а как при уменьшении экрана 2 колонки сделать тут надо javascripty позвонить, узнать что здесь можно намулить.

Comment: В какую сторону хоть рыть? Что гуглить подскажите!

Comment: Насколько много лет вы программируете? Год или 5? Я просто объясню так как понятнее будет

Comment: Полтора месяца назад прошел курсы Попова и ITVDN так и барахтаюсь

Comment: Хоть напишите куда копать? Я буду искать!

Comment: Теги Table и div. Завтра я ответ вам напишу 90%

Comment: http://risovach.ru/upload/2013/10/mem/apro_31165740_orig_.jpg

Comment: С помощью только CSS вы никак не сможете изменить _**последовательность вывода**_ блоков. CSS просто не предназначен для этого. Такая задача решается только через JS. Я бы посоветовал вам посмотреть в сторону [JS шаблонов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating). Они знач-но упрощают работу с динамическим выводом контента.

Comment: Во flexbox было что-то с последовательностью элементов. Прочитайте [статью](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/), пригодится.

Comment: разметку вы можете менять ?

Comment: @Кубик-рубик, глядите ответ пользователя greybutton, всё отлично работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью flexbox. Сделайте пример на весь экран, изменяйте ширину окна и увидите изменения. В написании css использован метод mobile first, но вы можете это сделать по-другому в зависимости от вашего подхода progressive enhancement или graceful degradation.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  width: 300px;
}
.image,
.text {
  width: 300px;
}
.image { background: lightgreen; }
.text { background: lightblue; }

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 500px;
  }
  .image,
  .text {
    width: 250px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    width: 900px;
  }
  .image,
  .text {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">Картинка-1</div>
  <div class="text">Текст-1</div>
  <div class="image">Картинка-2</div>
  <div class="text">Текст-2</div>
  <div class="image">Картинка-3</div>
  <div class="text">Текст-3</div>
</div>
```

Ссылки:

[Полное руководство по Flexbox (рус.)](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Mobile first (рус.)](http://lpgenerator.ru/blog/2016/03/16/strategiya-mobile-first-chto-eto-i-pochemu-na-nego-stoit-obratit-vnimanie/)

[Graceful Degradation (рус.)](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/izyashchnaya-degradatsiya)

[Progressive Enhancement (рус.)](http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/library/items/graphical_design/progressive-enhancement/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrap {
  width:100%;
  }

.wrap2 {
float:left;
 width: 66.66666%
}

.wrapleft {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f00;
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapright {
  width: 33.33333%;
  background: #0f0;
  height: 200px;
  float:right;
}

.wrap2 figure{
height: 100px;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  }

.wrap2 p {
height: 100px;
  width:50%;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  float:right;
  
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="wrap2">
  <div class="wrapleft">
     <figure>Картинка 1</figure>
     <p>Текст 1</p>
  </div>
  
   <div class="wrapleft">
    <figure>Картинка 2</figure>
     <p>Текст 2</p>
  </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="wrapright">
     <figure>Картинка 3</figure>
     <p>Текст 3</p>
  </div>
   
</div>
```

1) Меняем разметку. Думаю дальше не состоит труда Вам сделать и в 2-е колонки:

- картинка-1 текст-1
- картинка-2 текст-2
- картинка-3 текст-3

---

```
.wrapleft {
 width: 100%;
float:none;
}

.wrapright {
  width: 100%;
  float:none;
}
```

---

И в одну

- картинка-1
- текст -1
- картинка-2
- текст- 2
- картинка-3
- текст-3

*тут уже не сложно догадаться*

---

**Плюс:** решение **кроссбраузерное**, работает как в новых, так и в старых браузерах.

P.S. Если не знаете как - напишите комментарий.

Comment: не работает....

Comment: ну так ты media queries ставил ? я же не знаю какие тебе расширения нужно

Comment: что это? где именно?

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=media+queries&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_QnTV9yPNMLpsQHS3LgQ#q=media+queries+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: все работает нужно просто немного доделать под свои нужды